# JUnit testRunStarted method not called

Tags: java, junit

I want to run a method before all junit tests and one method after.The following link explains very well how to implement RunListener but I don't understand why tetRunStarted method is not called. This is the main reason I want to use RunListener however testRunFinished method works properly.

http://memorynotfound.com/add-junit-listener-example/

Answer (score 1):

In MyRunner class explicit notification should be added:

```
public class MyRunner extends BlockJUnit4ClassRunner {
...
@Override
public void run(RunNotifier notifier) {
    notifier.addListener(new JtmRunListener());
    notifier.fireTestRunStarted(getDescription());
    super.run(notifier);
}
...
}
```

Comment: A runner will be invoked for each test suite, so this would call the fireTestRunStarted method once per test suite, not once per test run. This distinction is especially relevant for nested test suites.

Comment: The Java docs for RunNotifier.fireTestRunStarted method explicitly say "Do not invoke."

Answer (score 0):

I believe the testRunStarted method is called, however the call happens at the very beginning of the test run, before a Runner can add a listener that would capture that call.